# When attempting to plot timeseries data with dates against floats I receive numbers in the xaxis instead of dates

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This has been troubling me and can't seem to get it to work, it should be an easy fix/tip if anyone can help.

I am using a simple example, with plotting my test, train, and avg (as a linear line) data, I am not able to get the dates shown in the x-axis.  My `dates` and `Total Fee` columns are `datetime64[ns]` and `float64` formats.

I assume it is because my date are not formatted correctly or I'm not defining something correctly in MatPlotLib.

Data example:

[image: Image of Data]

Code:

```
y_hat_avg = df_dem_test.copy()
y_hat_avg['avg_forecast'] = df_dem_train['Total Fee'].mean()
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8)

plt.plot(df_dem_train['Total Fee'], label='Train')
plt.plot(df_dem_test['Total Fee'], label='Test')
plt.plot(y_hat_avg['avg_forecast'], label='Average Forecast')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Current figure:

[image]

Comment: Try setting the date column as index: `df.set_index('dates', inplace=True)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like what @Shaido- Reinstate Monica said, you can try indexing. I had a similar problem and by indexing, I solved it

```
y_hat_avg = df_dem_test.copy()
y_hat_avg['avg_forecast'] = df_dem_train['Total Fee'].mean()


df_dem_train.set_index('dates', inplace=True)
df_dem_test.set_index('dates', inplace=True)
y_hat_avg.set_index('dates', inplace=True)

#Sort the index data before plotting

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))


plt.plot(df_dem_train['Total Fee'], label='Train')
plt.plot(df_dem_test['Total Fee'], label='Test')
plt.plot(y_hat_avg['avg_forecast'], label='Average Forecast')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Do keep in mind that `inplace=True` has to be mentioned, else a copy of the dataframe will be returned. I hope this works

Comment: Great that did work! Thank you. Though, now my line plots looks all wild and not continuous. Any tips on fixing that?

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by continuous ?

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work, I needed to sort the index data. It was plotting the dates out of order.

Comment: Oh I see, I had no idea about this sorting one. I am actually doing this in my project. Thanks